# What sort of temperatures do exhaust manifolds on large engines reach after normal operation?

Tags: engine, temperature, exhaust-manifold

The main car that I was wondering for was a Nissan Altima 2.5l 4dr. 2007 with 138,000 Miles

Comment: It would depend at what point? Are you running it for an hour, at which time it will be completely heat soaked? Or are you just getting the engine up to operating temps? Is the engine well tuned? Well tuned meaning, is it running at peak proficiency like you'd expect from the factory (new O2's, new plugs, etc).

Comment: It seems the consensus is around 1000-1200°F for exhaust gasses ... but it also depends on who you ask and where you look.

Comment: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/21474/7132

Answer (score 2):

It depends on many factors like operating revolutions, engine performance, manifold location (cooling), etc. If you are concerned about overheat - don't worry, hot manifold is okay. Some high performed engines can heat a manifold to yellow hot. Car engine could heat it to red hot. 
If your concern is safety of other components of a car, you can wrap your manifold in a heatproof bands, or make a shield of 2 - 3 layers of a thin aluminium sheet.

[image: dyno run at 8000 rpm]